# Can I add an svg that already exists on the page to another svg?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, geo

Here's the situation. I'm dynamically generating logos (i.e. they aren't external resources) as svgs using d3. I now have an svg map that I want to add those same logos to. Is there a way (with d3 or not) to copy those logos onto the map?  If it helps any my models are hanging onto a string representation of their full logo svg made from `new XMLSerializer().serializeToString()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can copy node hierarchies quite easily with JQuery by cloning the source and appending it to the target:

```
$("#source > svg").clone().appendTo("#target");
```

You can obviously also copy only parts of the SVG, e.g. the top-level group, this way.

Comment: Actually, any hints on how to center the top-level group on the target element?

Comment: Set the `transform` attribute to suitable `translate` values, i.e. half the width and half the height of the element.